# Calculated Product Price

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am wondering, how can I return calculated price of one product for product slider (Goal is to render a product slider with calculated prices for different customers, taxes, and so on). So far I've tried to use `Sales Channel Product Repository`, but didn't work (returns null)

Function where I use

```php
    public function onPageLoaded(PageLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        $context = $event->getContext();
        $salesChannelContext = $event->getSalesChannelContext();

        $page = $event->getPage();

        if (str_contains($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), '/link')) {
            $parts = explode("/link/", $event->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
            $toolId = $this->getToolIdBySlug($parts[1], $context);

            if ($toolId) {
                $toolsProducts = $this->getToolsProductByToolId($toolId, $context);
                $tools = [];
                $foo = [];
                foreach ($toolsProduct as $tool) {
                    $tools[] = $tool->getProduct();
                    $foo[] = $this->getSalesChannelProductById($tool->getProduct()->getId(), $salesChannelContext);

                }

                dd($foo); //NULL
            }
        }
    }
```

```php
    protected function getToolsProductByToolId(string $toolId, Context $context): array
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('toolId', $recipeId));
        $criteria->addAssociation('product');
        $criteria->addAssociation('product.cover');


        return $this->productToolRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getElements();
    }
```

SalesChannelProductRepository

```php
    protected function getSalesChannelProductById(string $productId, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): ?SalesChannelProductEntity
    {
        /** @var SalesChannelProductEntity|null $salesChannelProduct */
        $salesChannelProduct = $this->salesChannelProductRepository
            ->search(new Criteria([$productId]), $salesChannelContext)
            ->first();

        return $salesChannelProduct;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks ok to me. If the product with the id passed to `getSalesChannelProductById` is available within the sales channel of the context, then it should return an instance of `SalesChannelProductEntity`. Check that all the conditions of the responsible [`ProductAvailableFilter`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/8274db42d4281b34f96e51483343fbf3d44e9cc5/src/Core/Content/Product/SalesChannel/ProductAvailableFilter.php#L15) are met for the product in question.